# issue with cluster mongodb version 4.0 add member cluster

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, cluster-computing

the problem is when add a member to primary config server in cluster of mongodb 4.0

mongo.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  keyFile: /opt/mongo/keyfile
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr
replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 2048
  replSetName: configReplSet
```

> when add the first member no problem!! 
>   I use this code 
>   `configReplSet:PRIMARY> rs.add( { host: "mongo-config-1:27017",priority: 1, votes: 1 } )`

in this image show this

[image]

> when add the second server I have this problem!!

```
> rs.initiate(    {       _id: "configReplSet",       configsvr: true,       version: 1,       members: [          { _id: 0, host : "mongo-config-2:27017" },          { _id: 1, host : "mongo-config-3:27017" }       ]    } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The hosts mongo-config-2:27017 and mongo-config-3:27017 all map to this node in new configuration version 1 for replica set configReplSet",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
    }
}
```

>

----- update 2

host file:

```
xxx.xxx.136.16 localhost
xxx.xxx.136.16 mongo-config-1
xxx.xxx.138.105 mongo-config-2
xxx.xxx.193.244 mongo-config-3
xxx.xxx.128.156 mongo-query-router
xxx.xxx.129.70 mongo-shard-1
xxx.xxx.213.164 mongo-shard-2
```

I hope any idea!!!

-----update 3

I try with 
I install nmap in ubuntu and try to call the server with

> nmap -p 27017 mongo-config-2

the log is:

```
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
27017/tcp closed mongod
```

**in this case I use de bindIp: with "private IP"...**

I have problem with firewall???? any idea???

-------update 4----

this is rs.status() the node that can initiate

```
configReplSet:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "configReplSet",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-07-05T20:26:12.828Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(7),
    "syncingTo" : "",
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "configsvr" : true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(7)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(7)
        },
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(7)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(7)
        }
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongo-config-1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 2086,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(7)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-07-05T20:26:09Z"),
            "syncingTo" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1562356287, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-07-05T19:51:27Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000007")
    },
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1562358369, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"S8yWijAquqOMGOEW3txNtFK3jmA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6710234690252439578")
        }
    }
}
```

> problem with firewall in ubuntu 18.04 lts....

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Rather, post the text version of the message. Screenshots are not searchable so this will not help other people. The error message `mongo-config-1:27017 and mongo-config-3:27017 all map to this node` is the exact cause. Both names are pointing to the same IP address. Have you checked your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: @kevinadi thanks!! I update de post with de host file...

Comment: @kevinadi I update the post!!

Comment: i try with the numbers rs.add('xxx.xxx.xxx.244:27017') not work the same problem

Comment: i have problem with firewall?????

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what the issue is. Basically it's saying that `mongo-config-2` and `mongo-config-3` both arrive at the same IP. It's a network/deployment issue. Are you using docker/virtualization or some other routing? If you ping `mongo-config-2` and `mongo-config-3` from another host, does it show the same IP address?

Comment: I try to connect remote to server and I have this error  ..... [js] Error: couldn't connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.244:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.244:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :